# android tesseract too much slow

Tags: android, performance, ocr, tesseract

I have a serious issue with tesseract in android, it always takes a very long time to process a simple text with 10 short lines, about 1 or 2 minutes, and most of the time returns wrong results, more than 50% of error. I've tried to reduce the image size, binarize it, turn flash on while taking the photo, but none of this reduced the time spent or improved the quality of the results. Does someone know what I can do?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide some sample images? How large is your image?

Comment: im experiencing exactly the same problem i tested it on the emulator on the pc its actually much better, but as soon as i deploy to android and install on my phone it takes a minute or more to bring back results that really bad.